# How to change default parentheses formatting in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, code-formatting

Hi guys I'm new to C# and VisualStudio and I want to change the default formatting style from this:

```
 void Start()
 {
        
 }
```

To this:

```
 void Start() {

 }
```

Is it possible? Anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Take a look at Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> New Lines. There's are option for "Place open brace on new line for X". Untick any and all you want.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting-> New Lines`

You need to remove the check on all options here to never put the open bracket on a new line.

Comment: And solution for VS Code?